# Printing an existing PDF file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a pdf file my flutter folder named : `text.pdf` .

How can I print this file in Flutter with a button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `printing` package in pub.dev to help you out.

Inside your button's `onPressed` field, you can do this:

```dart
final pdf = await rootBundle.load('text.pdf');
await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => pdf.buffer.asUint8List());
```